# Apple Mach-O Linker Error in Xcode 6 after update Yosemite

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, project

I am developing an iOS application on Xcode 6. Until now, my program is running goodly. But a few minutes ago, I updated my macbook to OS X Yosemite. And now the Xcode is give an error when I build my project like as

```
"Apple mach-o linker error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)".
```

How can I fix it ? Please help me, I want to add this app on AppStore. Because this will be my first app in AppStore.

**edit:**

```
full description of the error; file not found: /Users/yusuf/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KTÜ_Bütünleme_Notu-dixnxduifyyourfbtrfxpchkvfjz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bütünleme.app/Bütünleme
```

I changed my app name yesterday to "Bütünleme" from "KTÜ Bütünleme Notu" as described there https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1625/_index.html

Comment: try to clean and rebuild